# How do I get an image stored in a javascript variable, to display in an HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

How do I get an image stored in a javascript variable, to display in an HTML code?

Say for instance, my image is stored in a variable called **flowers** as seen in the below javascript code:

```
<script>
     var flowers = "myFlowers.gif";
</script>
```

In the following HTML code, I reference the flowers variable in my **img src** in order to display the image but cant seem to get this to work.

```
<img src= flowers  class="card-img-top" id="flowers">
```

Please help, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless you're using some kind of special templating language... that markup will simply instruct the browser to set the image source to literally the string `flowers`, not the value of the variable. Use `document.getElementById('flowers').src = flowers;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert it directly like that. Instead you set the attribute `src` through javascript.

```js
let flowers = "https://picsum.photos/200/300";
document.querySelector('#flowers').src = flowers;
```

```html
<img  class="card-img-top" id="flowers">
```